Permutations with at least one cycle using only elements less than $\frac{n}{2}$
Consider some even number $n$. How many permutations are there such that there is at least one cycle with numbers $\le \frac{n}{2}$? The answer is: every other permutation- there are $\frac{n!}{2}$ such permutations.
Can we get this result from simple counting, or from some bijection, and without using generating functions?
This question comes from a probability brainteaser with $100$ boxes and keys, well-known enough to be found on this wiki page. It goes as follows: say you have n ordered boxes. Every box contains a key to some other box or possibly itself giving a permutation of the keys. You are allowed to select k of these n boxes all at once and break them open simultaneously, gaining access to k keys. What is the probability that using these keys you can open all n boxes, where you use a found key to open the box it belongs to and repeat? Equivalently, it is the probability that all cycles of a permutation contain at least one element from $1$ to $k$. Some computations involving generating functions show the result to be $\frac{k}{n}$.
In our case, with $k=\frac{n}{2}$, the probability that a random permutation has no cycle with only elements in the latter half (or the first half, ny symmetry) of $[1,n]$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. Can we get this result with elementary means?

You can use the Foata bijection to get a nice proof. Here is how this works. Given a permutation $\pi\in S_n$:

Write $\pi$ in cycle notation.

For each cycle, rewrite it so that the largest element comes first. E.g. $(1\;3\;6\;4)$ would be written $(6\;4\;3\;1)$.

Arrange the cycles in increasing order of their largest element.

Now, erase all of the parentheses, leaving just a list of $n$ numbers from $1$ to $n$ without repeats.


This correspondence is bijective; when you erase the parentheses, you do not lose any information, because you know there is an open parenthesis right before every number which is greater than all the numbers to its left.
This bijection gives a simple criterion to determine whether or not $\pi$ has a cycle consisting only of numbers of $\{1,\dots,n/2\}$. Consider the first number of the final list, call it $k$.
Then $\pi$ has a cycle on a subset of $\{1,\dots,n/2\}$ if and only if $k\le n/2$.

If $k$ is less than $n/2$, then since $k$ is the largest element of the first cycle of $\pi$, then $\pi$ has at least one cycle where all elements are at most $k$, and therefore at most $n/2$.

Conversely, if $k>n/2$, then since the cycles were arranged in increasing order of their largest element, this means every cycle has an element which is at least $k$, so at least $n/2+1$.


Since there are $n$ possible values for $k$, and $n/2$ of these outcomes cause $\pi$ to have a cycle with only elements from $\{1,\dots,n/2\}$, we conclude the fraction of permutations with such a cycle is exactly $1/2$, so there are $n!/2$ of them.

Quite convincing and concise an answer, thx!
